# Algorithm recommendation for calculating score jumps

Tags: algorithm

I've to come up with an algorithm which would determine jumps and changes of a person's personal scores. Just imagine that every day a person participates in a competition and the scores are recorded on daily basis. Now my task is to come up with a person's performance ratio based on provided time interval. For example: A person scored `7` yesterday, scored `6` today, which means the performance is negative: `-1` .

My current solution:
I've two collection of numbers which represents scores, where each element is a daily score of a person (three days):

```
dataFor2014-07-11/13 = {6,6,6}
dataFor2014-07-13/15 = {6,3,5}

double personsScores = AVG(dataFor2014-07-13/15) - AVG(dataFor2014-07-11/13);
Output: 4.6 - 6 = -1.3 (person's performance for past six days is negative.)
```

Do you think this is reasonable algorithm? Do you have any suggestions how can I improve it and recommend any better solution?

Comment: its neither an algorithm nor an mathematical problem, its only a question how you want to define a (caluclatable) performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more a mathematical problem and the Math forum would probably better to ask.

Probably, convolution filters are the way to go. This is a technique to make a 'graph' through some points (the individual scores).